# What should the Gradle:module:app look like to compile to an Android 2.3.3/Gingerbread?

Tags: android, gradle, compiler-errors, sdk

Here is my Gradle file.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 10
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.loadrunner"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 10
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

I see alot of errors on compiling dealing with library levels and they all go down the code detail rabbit hole. The problem in all cases seems to be library levels and correct SDK levels. I have tried many hours at this like others with specific problems and have found nothing to solve my library problem. Is there something simple I can do beside turning the machine off?
This app worked at one version till I needed to add more functionality and this could be the catch. Items are showing up with no parent references that used to not show up in error.

The Gradle error is this:

> Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.

Flipping version numbers around to me seems to not be the answer. But then that just could be the simple truth.

I appreciate the help and thank you.

Comment: So today I turned on machine, loaded all versions of my app and ran in emulator and on HTC EVO. They all work. I see instability on AS IntelliJ IDE. The latest version wouldn't build at all and today there are no crashes on phone with rebuild. I will leave this question in StackOverflow as an example to of sometimes being a developer it is not the developer but the environment. BSCP / B.S. Computer problems.  Who do I send this to for further platform analysis?

Comment: As i progress further on in development what do I mistrust? My dev progress or the failed IDE?